# Segmentation error when I try to sort linked list using the function MAX()

Tags: c++

so I've an assignment to sort single linked list ascending and descending wise here's the code, in my head it should work as getting the maximum and adding it into a new list and delete the max in order to find the new maximum of the old list.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node {
   int data;
   Node* next;
           };
Node * createNode(int x)
{
   Node * newnode = new Node;
   newnode-> data = x;
   newnode-> next = NULL;
   return newnode;
}
class List {
Node *head;
public: 
   List()
   {
       head=NULL;
   }
   void Delete(int x)
   {
   Node* q;
   Node* p = head;
   while(head->data==x && head!=NULL)
       {
           q=head;
           head=head->next;
           delete(q);
       }
   p=head;
   while(p->next!=NULL)
   {
       if(p->next->data==x)
       {
           q=p->next;
           p->next=p->next->next;
           delete(q);
       }
       else
       {
          p=p->next; 
       }
   }
   }



   void InsertAtBeggining(int x)
{
Node* newnode = createNode(x);
   if(head==NULL)
       {
           head=newnode;
       }
   else 
       {   
           newnode->next=head;
           head=newnode; 
       }
   }

void InsertLast(int x)
{
   Node* newnode = createNode(x);
   Node* p=head;
   if(head==NULL)
       {
           head=newnode;
       }
       else 
       {   
           while(p->next!=NULL) // 4 5 6 7
           {
               p=p->next;
           }
           p->next=newnode;
           newnode->data=x;
           newnode->next=NULL;
                 
       }

}
int MAX()
{
   Node *p=head;
   int m=p->data;
   if(head==NULL)
       {
           cout<<"List is empty! ";

       }
       else
       {
           while(p!=NULL)
           {
               if(p->data>m)
               {
                   m=p->data;
                   p=p->next;
               }
               else{
                 p=p->next;  
               }
               
           }
           return m;
       }
}
int MIN()
{
   Node *p=head;
   int m=p->data;
   if(head==NULL)
       {
           cout<<"List is empty! ";

       }
       else
       {
           while(p!=NULL)
           {
               if(p->data<m)
               { 
                   m=p->data;
                   p=p->next;
               }
               else{
                 p=p->next;  
               }
           }
           return m;
       }
}


int size()
{
   int count = 0;
   Node* current = head;
   while (current != NULL)
   {
       count++;
       current = current->next;
   }
   return count;
}

/*   int locate(int x) {
       node* p = head;
       int c = 0;
       
       while (p != NULL) {
           if (p->data != x) {
               p = p->next;
               c++;
               
           }
           else {
              return c; 
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }

*/
List Ascending_sorting(List l)
{
   List l2 = List();
   int c=l.size();
   while (c!=0)
   {
       int x=l.MAX();
       l2.InsertAtBeggining(x);
       l.Delete(MAX());
       c--;
        l2.print();
       cout<<endl;
   }
   l2.print();   
}
/*
List Descending_sorting(List l)
{
   List l2 = List();
   int c=l.size();
   while (c!=0)
   {
       int x=l.MAX();
       l2.InsertLast(x);
       l.Delete(MAX());
       c--;
   }
   cout<<"tany print"<<endl;
   l2.print();   
}

*/
   void print()
{
   Node *p=head;
   while(p!=NULL)
   {
       cout<<p->data<<endl;
       p=p->next;
   }
}

};
 int main()
   {   
       List l;
       l.InsertAtBeggining(9);
       l.InsertAtBeggining(2);
       l.InsertAtBeggining(3);
       l.InsertAtBeggining(4);
       l.InsertAtBeggining(1);
       l.InsertLast(30);
       l.InsertLast(20);
       l.InsertLast(60);
       l.InsertLast(10);
       l.InsertLast(90);
       int z;
       z = l.MAX();
       cout<<"max "<<z<<endl;
       l.Ascending_sorting(l);
       system("PAUSE");
       return 0;
   }
```

I'd like any help :) it's printing l2 inside the while loop but it fails outside of it, also it's not printing the 1.

Comment: `p->next` could be null in `p->next->next`. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @AlanBirtles in which method? the error started occuring after i wrote the sorting functions

Comment: That's only in your code once so hopefully it's fairly obvious?

Comment: Be careful with your pointers. Ex: consider the sense of `Node *p = head; int m = p->data; if (head == NULL) {...}`. Now ask yourself, if that test for `head` being null is possibly true, and `p` just two lines earlier was set to the value of `head`, what do you think `p->data` is going to do? Also, turn up your warnings. You have multiple functions that declare they return values but have code paths that allow function exit without ever actually returning anything.

Comment: Side note:  your List class should also have a member that points to the _last_ element of the list, then `InsertLast` will be much more efficient, because you don't need to find the last element each time. Imagine your list has 100000 elements. For inserting another element your `while(p->next!=NULL)` loop will run 100000 times.

Comment: @Jabberwocky makes a lot of sense..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should check before derefrence pointers!

actually I changed these lines:

```
while((head != NULL) && head->data == x)
```

```
while((p != NULL) && p->next != NULL)
```

and after changed you have this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};
Node* createNode(int x)
{
    Node* newnode = new Node;
    newnode->data = x;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    return newnode;
}
class List
{
    Node* head;

public:
    List()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
    void Delete(int x)
    {
        Node* q;
        Node* p = head;
        while((head != NULL) && head->data == x)
        {
            q = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete(q);
        }
        p = head;
        while((p != NULL) && p->next != NULL)
        {
            if(p->next->data == x)
            {
                q = p->next;
                p->next = p->next->next;
                delete(q);
            }
            else
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
        }
    }

    void InsertAtBeggining(int x)
    {
        Node* newnode = createNode(x);
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            newnode->next = head;
            head = newnode;
        }
    }

    void InsertLast(int x)
    {
        Node* newnode = createNode(x);
        Node* p = head;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            head = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            while(p->next != NULL) // 4 5 6 7
            {
                p = p->next;
            }
            p->next = newnode;
            newnode->data = x;
            newnode->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    int MAX()
    {
        Node* p = head;
        int m = p->data;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "List is empty! ";
        }
        else
        {
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                if(p->data > m)
                {
                    m = p->data;
                    p = p->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    p = p->next;
                }
            }
            return m;
        }
    }
    int MIN()
    {
        Node* p = head;
        int m = p->data;
        if(head == NULL)
        {
            cout << "List is empty! ";
        }
        else
        {
            while(p != NULL)
            {
                if(p->data < m)
                {
                    m = p->data;
                    p = p->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    p = p->next;
                }
            }
            return m;
        }
    }

    int size()
    {
        int count = 0;
        Node* current = head;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            count++;
            current = current->next;
        }
        return count;
    }

    /*   int locate(int x) {
       node* p = head;
       int c = 0;

       while (p != NULL) {
           if (p->data != x) {
               p = p->next;
               c++;

           }
           else {
              return c;
           }
       }
       return -1;
   }

*/
    List Ascending_sorting(List l)
    {
        List l2 = List();
        int c = l.size();
        while(c != 0)
        {
            int x = l.MAX();
            l2.InsertAtBeggining(x);
            l.Delete(MAX());
            c--;
            l2.print();
            cout << endl;
        }
        l2.print();
    }
    /*
List Descending_sorting(List l)
{
   List l2 = List();
   int c=l.size();
   while (c!=0)
   {
       int x=l.MAX();
       l2.InsertLast(x);
       l.Delete(MAX());
       c--;
   }
   cout<<"tany print"<<endl;
   l2.print();
}

*/
    void print()
    {
        Node* p = head;
        while(p != NULL)
        {
            cout << p->data << endl;
            p = p->next;
        }
    }
};
int main()
{
    List l;
    l.InsertAtBeggining(9);
    l.InsertAtBeggining(2);
    l.InsertAtBeggining(3);
    l.InsertAtBeggining(4);
    l.InsertAtBeggining(1);
    l.InsertLast(30);
    l.InsertLast(20);
    l.InsertLast(60);
    l.InsertLast(10);
    l.InsertLast(90);
    int z;
    z = l.MAX();
    cout << "max " << z << endl;
    l.Ascending_sorting(l);
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What have you changed? Why did you change it? What was the problem? Just posting code is rarely a useful answer. From a quick look I think your code will never delete the last node in the list?

Comment: you can read my post , check before derefrence , is better advice than showing my change in multiple times ! , I said solution then fixed problem .@AlanBirtles